# DAPP creation problem: Output not shown in the webpage (problem with the interface or function definition)

Tags: javascript, html, solidity, decentralized-applications

I know its a long post and thanks in advance to everyone that spends the time to read it.

We are building a Dapp called Forest. The idea is that it asks you if you are a producer or a customer and then if you pick producer it asks you to register a tree, but if you choose customer it asks you to give the dna code of a tree and then retrieves and dispaly the information if a tree with that dna has been registered. Everything works fine except that I cant make information to appear on the screen in the final stage.

*The output(Information) appears in the console, but not in the webpage!

Im showing my solidity file, my app.js and html.

Here is my solidity code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5;

contract Forest {
    string public name;
    uint public treeCount = 0;
    mapping(string => Tree) private trees;
      //UserType public userType;

    enum UserType {Producer, Customer}

     struct Tree {
        string dna;
        string country;
        int256 latitude;
        int256 longitude;
        string treeType;
    }

    event TreeRegistered(
        string dna,
        string country,
        int256 latitude,
        int256 longitude,
        string treeType
    );

    constructor() public {
        name = "Tree Identification";
    }

    function registerTree(
        string memory _dna,
        string memory _country,
        int256 _latitude,
        int256 _longitude,
        string memory _treeType
    ) public {
        // Make sure all information are filled correctly
        require(bytes(_dna).length > 0, "DNA code must not be empty");
        require(bytes(_country).length > 0, "Country must not be empty");
        require(_latitude != 0 && _longitude != 0, "Latitude and longitude must be provided");
        require(bytes(_treeType).length > 0, "Tree type must not be empty");
        // Check if the DNA code is already used for a registered tree
        require(trees[_dna].latitude == 0 && trees[_dna].longitude == 0, "DNA code already used for a registered tree");
        //Tree count
        treeCount ++;
        //Register Tree
        trees[_dna] = Tree(_dna, _country, _latitude, _longitude, _treeType);
        //Triger Event
        emit TreeRegistered(_dna, _country, _latitude, _longitude, _treeType);
    }

    //function setUserType(UserType _userType) public {
    //    userType = _userType;
    //}


    function getTreeInformation(string memory _dna) public view returns (string memory, string memory, int256, int256, string memory) {
        // Find the tree
        Tree memory _tree = trees[_dna];
        // Return tree information
        return (_tree.dna, _tree.country, _tree.latitude, _tree.longitude, _tree.treeType);
    }
}
```

Here is my app.js

```
App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},
  account: '0x0',
  userType: null, // Add userType property

  // Add UserType enum definition
  UserType: {
    Producer: "producer",
    Customer: "customer"
  },

  init: function() {
    return App.initWeb3();
  },

  initWeb3: function() {
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      // If a web3 instance is already provided by MetaMask.
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
      // Specify default instance if no web3 instance provided
      App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:9545');
      web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
    }
    return App.initContract();
  },

  initContract: function() {
    $.getJSON("Forest.json", function(forest) {
      // Instantiate a new truffle contract from the artifact
      App.contracts.Forest = TruffleContract(forest);
      // Connect provider to interact with contract
      App.contracts.Forest.setProvider(App.web3Provider);

      return App.render();
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    var forestInstance;
    var loader = $("#loader");
    var content = $("#content");
    var userTypeSelector = $("#userTypeSelector");
    var userTypeForm = $("#userTypeForm");

    loader.show();
    content.hide();

    // Load account data
    web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
      if (err === null) {
        App.account = account;
        $("#accountAddress").html("Your Account: " + account);
      }
    });

    // Show user type selection form
    userTypeForm.show();

    // Handle user type selection
    userTypeSelector.on("submit", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var selectedUserType = $("input[name=userType]:checked").val();
      if (selectedUserType === App.UserType.Producer) {
        App.userType = App.UserType.Producer;
        App.registerTree();
      } else if (selectedUserType === App.UserType.Customer) {
        App.userType = App.UserType.Customer;
        App.getTreeInformation();
      } else {
        console.log("Invalid user type. Please try again.");
      }
    });
    
    // Get tree count and display it
    App.contracts.Forest.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      forestInstance = instance;
      return forestInstance.treeCount();
    }).then(function(count) {
      $("#treeCount").html("Tree Count: " + count.toNumber());
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error('Error getting tree count:', error);
    });

  
    loader.hide();
    content.show();
  },

  handleUserType: function() {
    var selectedUserType = $("#userTypeSelect").val();
    if (selectedUserType === "Producer") {
      App.userType = App.UserType.Producer;
      $("#producerForm").show();
      $("#customerForm").hide();
      $("#treeInfo").empty();
    } else if (selectedUserType === "Customer") {
      App.userType = App.UserType.Customer;
      $("#customerForm").show();
      $("#producerForm").hide();
      $("#treeInfo").empty();
    } else {
      console.log("Invalid user type. Please try again.");
    }
  },

  registerTree: function() {
    // Get the required inputs from the user (DNA, country, latitude, longitude, tree type)
      var dna = $("#dnaInputProducer").val();
      var country = $("#countryInput").val();
      var latitude = parseFloat($("#latitudeInput").val());
      var longitude = parseFloat($("#longitudeInput").val());
      var treeType = $("#treeTypeInput").val();

    App.contracts.Forest.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      return instance.registerTree(dna, country, latitude, longitude, treeType, { from: App.account });
    }).then(function(result) {
      console.log('Tree registered successfully!');
      console.log('Transaction Hash:', result.tx);
      // Display success message on the page
      $("#successMessage").text('Success');
      $("#successMessage").show();
      // Bind a click event to the document to hide the success message when clicked
      $(document).on('click', function() {
        $("#successMessage").hide();
        // Unbind the click event after it's triggered once
        $(document).off('click');
      });
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error('Error registering tree:', error);
      // Display the error message on the page
      $("#errorMessage").text(error.message);
      $("#errorMessage").show();
    });
  },

  getTreeInformation: function() {
    // Get the required input from the user (DNA)
    var dna = $("#dnaInputCustomer").val();

    App.contracts.Forest.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      return instance.getTreeInformation(dna);
    }).then(function(treeInfo) {
      if (treeInfo[0] === "") {
        // Display failure message if DNA is not found
        $("#failureMessage").text('DNA not found');
        $("#failureMessage").show();
        // Bind a click event to the document to hide the failure message when clicked
        $(document).on('click', function() {
          $("#failureMessage").hide();
          // Unbind the click event after it's triggered once
          $(document).off('click');
        });
      } else {
        console.log('Tree Information:');
        console.log('DNA:', treeInfo[0]);
        console.log('Country:', treeInfo[1]);
        console.log('Latitude:', treeInfo[2]);
        console.log('Longitude:', treeInfo[3]);
        console.log('Tree Type:', treeInfo[4]);
        // Display the tree information on the page
        $("#treeInfo").show();
        $("#dnaOutput").text('DNA: ' + treeInfo[0]);
        $("#countryOutput").text('Country: ' + treeInfo[1]);
        $("#latitudeOutput").text('Latitude: ' + treeInfo[2]);
        $("#longitudeOutput").text('Longitude: ' + treeInfo[3]);
        $("#treeTypeOutput").text('Tree Type: ' + treeInfo[4]);

        // Hide the failure message (if shown)
        $("#failureMessage").hide();
      }  

    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error('Error getting tree information:', error);
    });
  }
};


$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    App.init();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Set form references
  App.userTypeForm = $("#userTypeForm");
  App.producerForm = $("#producerForm");
  App.customerForm = $("#customerForm");
  App.treeInfo = $("#treeInfo");

  // Hide the producer and customer forms initially
  App.producerForm.hide();
  App.customerForm.hide();

  // Add event listener to the user type form
  App.userTypeForm.on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var userType = $('input[name=userType]:checked', '#userTypeForm').val();

    if (userType === "producer") {
      // Show the producer form
      App.producerForm.show();
      App.customerForm.hide();
      App.treeInfo.empty();
    } else if (userType === "customer") {
      // Show the customer form
      App.customerForm.show();
      App.producerForm.hide();
      App.treeInfo.empty();
    }
  });
});

//ENABLES METAMASK LOGIN
const ethEnabled = async () => {
  if (window.ethereum) {
    await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
    window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};

login = function() {
  if (!ethEnabled()) {
    alert("Please use an Ethereum-compatible browser or install an extension like MetaMask to use this dApp");
  } else {
    App.init();
  }
};
```

and here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Forest DAPP</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" style="width: 650px;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h1 class="text-center">Forest DAPP</h1>
          <hr/>
          <br/>
          <div id="loader">
            <p class="text-center">Loading...</p>
          </div>
          <div id="content" style="display: none;">
            <div id="userTypeForm">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="userTypeSelect">Select User Type</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="userTypeSelect">
                  <option value="Producer">Producer</option>
                  <option value="Customer">Customer</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="App.handleUserType()">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <div id="producerForm" style="display: none;">
              <form id="producerForm" onSubmit="App.registerTree(); return false;">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="dnaInputProducer">DNA</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dnaInputProducer" placeholder="Enter DNA">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="countryInput">Country</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="countryInput" placeholder="Enter Country">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="latitudeInput">Latitude</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="latitudeInput" placeholder="Enter Latitude">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="longitudeInput">Longitude</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="longitudeInput" placeholder="Enter Longitude">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="treeTypeInput">Tree Type</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="treeTypeInput" placeholder="Enter Tree Type">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register Tree</button>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div id="customerForm" style="display: none;">
              <form id="customerForm" onSubmit="App.getTreeInformation(); return false;">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="dnaInputCustomer">DNA</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dnaInputCustomer" placeholder="Enter DNA">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Get Tree Information</button>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div id="treeInfo" style="display: none;">
              <h3>Tree Information</h3>
              <p id="dnaOutput"></p>
              <p id="countryOutput"></p>
              <p id="latitudeOutput"></p>
              <p id="longitudeOutput"></p>
              <p id="treeTypeOutput"></p> 
            </div>
            <div id="treeCount"></div>
            <div id="successMessage" class="alert alert-success" style="display: none;"></div> 
            <div id="failureMessage" class="alert alert-failure" style="display: none;"></div> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <style>
      .alert-success {
        margin-top: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>
    
    <style>
      .alert-failure {
        margin-top: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>
    
    
 <!-- button necessary to connect Metamask to port-->
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-l pull-right" style="margin-top: 30px;" onclick="login()">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> CONNECT METAMASK</button>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/web3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/truffle-contract.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please make any suggestions.

Comment: Can you share with us the error message?

Comment: there is no error msg, it just does nothing. I know it does the dna matching bacause if you put a dna that is not register you get a "DNA not found" msg. But if you put a DNA that exists you get no output